# SML - last in list

Tags: list, sml

I want the last value in list of SML.

for example, `1::2::3 => 3`

I tried use "last", but it didn't work.

I tried to implement it, like this:

```
val rec last =
    fn (h::list) => last (list)
       | (h::nil) => h
       | (nil) => nil;
```

But it gives me problem: match redundant.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that the case of `(h::nil)` is redundant because it is a special case of `(h::list)`. I think you should reorder your match cases:

```
    exception Empty
    val rec last =
        fn (h::nil) => h
           |(h::list) => last (list)
           | (nil) => raise Empty;
```

By the way, `List.last` should work because it's a part of SML Basis Library.

Comment: Thank you, but It didnt work. It say that the operator domain should get 'z list list, but I gives him int list.

Comment: It happens because you have nothing to return when the input list is nil. I have updated the code which raises an exception when the list is empty.

Comment: `List` is part of the SML Basis Library, not just SML/NJ

Answer (score 2):

Could also be done as easy as that:

```
exception Empty
fun lastinList [] = raise Empty
| lastinList l = hd(rev(l));
```

Comment: Why the special handling of `[]`? `fun last xs = hd (rev xs)` is just as good.

Comment: Well obviously there is no last item in an empty list, that's why i think you should raise an error if the list is empty. But as you said, the reduced code is just as good.